# Creating a test project for Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

Here's the issue I'm having

1. Create `Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) in Visual Studio`
2. Include all the Nuget packages and dll references I need (The Functions I want to test against happen to be `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`)
3. Write unit test for a Function
4. Try to compile project
5. Get error

> The target "RunResolvePublishAssemblies" does not exist in the project

6. I can find barely any info about this on the internet. The most is https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/92
7. I do notice that my `MyFATests.cproj` has a completely different structure than my Function App `MyFA.csproj`'s project structure
8. I try the suggestion of adding `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` in my test project's `Project` tag to see if this makes a quick fix
9. New and existing compile error:

> Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes
>   'Compile' items from your project directory by default. ...

10. Tried commenting out all the `<Compile Include...>` tags.
11. New compile error (Giving up trying to "convert" my project into an Microsoft.NET.Sdk type)

Any guidance? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no out-of-box support in Visual Studio for creating unit test projects for Azure Functions. Here are some documented approaches to testing Azure Functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function